# Native custom file dialog PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

In my PyQt app I'm trying to run native but custom QFileDialog.
My code looks like this.

```
dlg = QtGui.QFileDialog(self, caption=self.tr("Select a file")))
dlg.setNameFilters("Text files (*.txt)")

if dlg.exec_():
    name = dlg.selectedFiles()
```

but this shows a Qt dialog, not native. I've tried

```
dlg.setOption(QtGui.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog, False)
```

but this didn't help.
How do I run custom native QFileDialog?

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the native File Dialogs by using the static functions on `QFileDialog`.  The `DontUseNativeDialog` option only works when using the static functions.

[`QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName), etc.

From the [Docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qfiledialog.html)

> The easiest way to create a QFileDialog is to use the static functions. On Windows, Mac OS X, KDE and GNOME, these static functions will call the native file dialog when possible.
>
> ```
> QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog   0x00000010
> ```
>
> Don't use the native file dialog. By default, the native file dialog is used unless you use a subclass of QFileDialog that contains the Q_OBJECT macro.

Answer (score 1):

A *custom* native dialog is a contradiction interms. The main reason for choosing to use a native dialog is so that you can get *exactly* what the platform normally provides.

But this is a moot point, since [getOpenFileName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName) allows you to achieve what you want without any customization:

```
name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            parent=self,
            caption=self.tr("Select a file"),
            filter=self.tr('Text files (*.txt)'),
            )
if name:
    print(name)
```

In addition to the above arguments, there's also `dir`, which allows you to set the *start directory*; `selectedFilter`, which allows you to set the *initial filter*; and `options`, which allows you to set one or more [Option values](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) (not all of which are relevant for native file-dialogs).